# Prioritizing data collection

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

In toxicology machine learning methods are used to estimate the probability of compound toxicity.

Unfortunately most toxicology datasets contain on the order of 100 compounds and sometimes contain many more variables than compounds.

When organizing the creation of new data one might ask how we can use a generative model to determine which chemicals would be valuable to test next, and which tests to perform on those chemicals.

The goal of such data collection would be to improve the underlying model as quickly as possible.  After doing some searching I have not found any papers approaching this question.  Is anybody aware of methods used to organize data collection to improve the predictivity of a machine learning model as quickly as possible?

Comment: This post isn't about designing toxins, its about discovering which compounds are toxic, so that we can stop using them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about modelling this problem with decision bayesian networks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influence_diagrams)? If you can define some utility function that you can optimise, given the decision you make, that is, which chemicals should be tested. This is a kind of a problem, when you take decisions under uncertainty, which looks like the situation you describe.

I know it's quite abtract response, but maybe it will guide you into the right direction.